# root to launchrock subdomain using rails 3.1 routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I created a launchrock page as a subdomain, signup.mysite.com, and I would like to redirect people from mysite.com to the the launchrock subdomain.  How would I set this up in the routes.rb file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Rails 3, you can set a redirect for your root path:

```
# config/routes.rb
root :to => redirect("http://signup.mysite.com")
```

This will only affect traffic coming in to the root of the app ("http://mysite.com"), but not any links or URIs hitting the apps controllers (like "http://mysite.com/users/"). This may or may not be beneficial, depending on your intentions.

If you want all routes be redirected to LaunchRock, or for Rails 2, you can set a small before filter:

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb

before_filter :redirect_everyone_away_from_rails

def :redirect_everyone_away_from_rails
  redirect_to("http://signup.mysite.com")
end
```

Does that cover it?